# Which primary scriptures (that are not commentaries or disputations) cite other scriptures?

Tags: scripture

I am not merely talking about one scripture mentioning another scripture (like Purana A describing Purana B as "Tamasic") - I am talking about naming other scriptures along with the cited content.

Obviously, Bhashyams and Tikas have to mention the scripture they are commenting on and I would exclude those cases too.

If there are many, a handful of scriptures naming and citing other scriptures are sufficient.

Comment: This is found in many Tantras .. Like in Nityo Shodashika Arnava Lord Shiva  says to Devi " I have already described about [a particular topic] in Rudrayamala"

Comment: please expand into an answer @rickross

Comment: I will hv to chk for all those verses .. too tired to do that  right now .. let me do it tomorrow ok?

Comment: "primary scriptures" includes Itihasas?

Comment: of course ! @sv.

Comment: I was going to answer by quoting verses from [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16207/) but in the Critical Edition of Ramayana, the reference to Manu is gone!

Comment: Ramayana quoting manusmriti?  isn't that an anachronism? @sv.

Comment: @SK Maybe that's why CE removed the reference. But they still kept the verses, only the previous verse with direct reference to Manu is removed. It's possible VR is referring to an even older dharma shastra than Manu.

Answer (score 2):

> Which primary scriptures (that are not commentaries or disputations) show awareness of other scriptures?

**The *Grihya Sutras* frequently refer to mantras in the Vedas.**

From the *Ashvalayana Grihya Sutras:*

> **[3.](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/sbe29111.htm)** **With the Rik**, 'Where thou knowest, O tree' (Rig-veda V, 5, 10), let him make two lumps (of food), put them on a carrying-pole, hand them over to the messenger, and say to him, 'Carry this Bali to that (Kaitya).'
>
> **[1.](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/sbe29112.htm)** **The Upanishad** [probably the Upanishad belonging to the Ashvalayana Sakha] (treats of) the Garbhalambhana, the Pumsavana, and the Anavalobhana (i.e. the ceremonies for securing the conception of a child, the male gender of the child, and for preventing disturbances which could endanger the embryo).
>
> **[3.](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/sbe29113.htm)** Then he gives its place to the fire, and having spread to the west of it a bull's hide with the neck to the east, with the hair outside, (he makes oblations,) while (his wife) is sitting on that (hide) and takes hold of him, with the two (verses), 'May Dhâtri give to his worshipper,' with the two verses, 'I invoke Râkâ' (Rig-veda II, 32, 4 seq.), and with (the texts), 'Negamesha,' and, 'Pragâpati, no other one than thou' (Rig-Veda X, 121, 10).

And many more.

Answer (score 2):

Uddhava Gita section in Bhagavatam refers Bhagavad Gita

SB 11.16.7: On the Battlefield of Kurukṣetra Arjuna thought that killing his relatives would be an abominable, irreligious activity, motivated only by his desire to acquire a kingdom. He therefore desisted from the battle, thinking, “I would be the killer of my relatives. They would be destroyed.” Thus Arjuna was afflicted with mundane consciousness.

SB 11.16.8: At that time I enlightened Arjuna, the tiger among men, with logical arguments, and thus in the front of the battle Arjuna addressed Me with questions in the same way that you are now inquiring.

And then Krishna almost tells same things as 10th chapter of bhagavad gita.

Also here 1.15.30 of Bhagavatam

गीतं भगवता ज्ञानं यत्तत्सङ्ग्राममूर्धनि ।
कालकर्मतमोरुद्धं पुनरध्यगमत्प्रभुः

It says Arjuna recollected Bhagavad Gita spoken in battle field which he had forgotten due to time factor and thus again became master.